# How to get information from other pages in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I'm starting on react native and I'm having a hard time, I would like to take the information from another page and show this data on this new page. For example I am creating an application for my college work, where it is about soccer players, and it has a screen that shows the list of these players, but I am creating a page with more details about the player clicked.

Below is the code I created that I can replicate the players.

listaIndex.js

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {Text, View,StyleSheet,Image} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class JogadoresLista extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewDentro}>
        <View style={styles.viewTop}>
          <Image source={this.props.imageUri} style={styles.imagem} />
            <View style={styles.viewBottom}>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>{this.props.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>{this.props.posicao}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );  
}
}
```

Below is the code I created that I can show the players.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import JogadoresLista from '../jogadores/listaIndex';
import logoG from '../../images/icon.png';

export default function Home({navigation}) { 
  function navigateToPlayers(){
    navigation.navigate('Detalhes');
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={styles.home}>
    <ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16}>
    <View style={styles.logoView}>
            <Image source={logoG} style={styles.imageLogo}/>
            <View>
            <Text style={styles.texto}>Principais Jogadores</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textoL}>GodoySoccer</Text>
            </View>
      </View>
      <ScrollView horizontal={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <JogadoresLista
              imageUri={require('../../images/ronald-juv.jpg')}
              name="Cristiano Ronaldo"
              posicao="Extremo Esquerdo"/>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.botao} title="Detalhes" onPress={(navigateToPlayers)}>
                  <Text style={styles.textoB}>Detalhes</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>              
          </ScrollView>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Below is the code I can't create to show the clicked player data 
detalhesJogadores.js

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {Text, View, Image,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';



export default function DetalhesPlayers() {  
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewDentro}>
        <View style={styles.viewTop}>
          {/* Player Name */}
          <Text>{this.props.name}</Text> 
          {/* Player Position */}
          <Text style={styles.textoP}>{this.props.posicao}</Text>
          {/* Player Image */}
          <Image source={this.props.imageUri} style={styles.imagem} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );  
}
```

I would like some help to be able to solve this problem, because it is for my college work and I don't know where to start

[Screen showing players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb3kC.png)
[Screen showing player data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpJSp.png)

Comment: It looks like you clicked on Detalhes(index.js) and want to navigate to DetalhesPlayers?
something like `onPress() {
  navigation.navigate(
    'DetalhesPlayers',
    { imageUri:'abc',
name:'def'}
  );
}`

Comment: but how can I put the code on my DetalhesPlayers page, to be able to get these parameters that I put in navigation.navigate?

Comment: You have set `this.props.imageUri` like this, it will get the parameters from props when you call it, because I use `react-native-router-fulx` so I'm not sure the correct code is `navigation.navigate` or something like `navigation.push` , but the direction should correct.

Comment: But I think it should be like `onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate( 'DetalhesPlayers', { imageUri:'abc', name:'defg'} )
        }`
Maybe change the 'name', it could duplicate to the route name?  You can realize more from [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parameters in navigation to Details page inside the navigateToPlayer(). Retrieve the paramters in Details page and then display.

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: Inside your index.js you are navigating through navigateToPlayer(). Inside this function set parameter describing the selected player using props.navigation.setParams(). Then use this paramter inside Details page by using props.navigation.setParam().